# MySQL: Enum vs Varchar-with-Index

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, database-design, sqldatatypes

Suppose, I have a requirement to create a table where one of the column will be having a value from this limited and never-changing set: 
'all', 'local', 'qa', 'staging', and 'production'.

Using `enum` data type for this situation looks like a suitable solution but after reading [this article](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) and some other threads on the internet, I feel discouraged to use it. So, if I do **not** want to create a lookup table **and** keeping the combination of `evn` and `name` unique is also a requirement then what is my best options between a column with ENUM type and a column with VARCHAR type but with an index created on it.

Also considering that the insertion in this table will be rare and we want this particular query to execute faster:

```
SELECT `enabled` FROM `features`
WHERE `name` = 'some_featuere'
AND `env` IN('all', 'qa')
ORDER BY `enabled` ASC limit 1;
```

Which one of these is a better design and why?

```
CREATE TABLE `features` (
  `id` INTEGER  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  `env` ENUM('all', 'local', 'qa', 'staging', 'production') NOT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` DATETIME,
  `updated_at` DATETIME,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_unq_features_name_env` (`name`,`env`)
);
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE `features` (
  `id` INTEGER  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  `env` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` DATETIME,
  `updated_at` DATETIME,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `idx_features_env` (`env`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_unq_features_name_env` (`name`,`env`)
);
```

Comment: You don't want a lookup table, that's bad. Use integers. You have 5 options. Don't overengineer this. Use the lookup table, don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "neither" because your query would use an index on name/env in both scenarios. However, if I had to settle on one, I'd go for VARCHAR over ENUM as the lesser to two evils but I think there might be some other issues with your approach.

First, the VARCHAR option is only going to duplicate an issue with ENUM mentioned in that article (i.e. the addition of attributes or related data) while losing possibly the only advantage you might gain from ENUM, that of data integrity. You'd get data integrity via a lookup without the evilness of the ENUM.

Second, you might be focusing on a performance issue that doesn't exist with the query. How often is it run? How slow is it? As it stands, you have a  index on `NAME`/`ENV` and the only way I can't think of to speed up the query would be a covering index to include `ENABLED` but I doubt it's a performance killer as it is and I suspect you'd see very little difference joining to a lookup table.

Third, 'ALL' as an option makes very little sense unless a feature should only ever be deployed in one environment at a time or in ALL of them simultaneously. If that doesn't hold true, you would necessarily have to delete all other records related to the feature name whenever you wanted to apply the 'ALL' option. 'ALL' would also prevent selectively enabling/disabling features in different environments or separately recording create/update events. That's introducing data management issues that don't need to exist.

Fourth, while the columns `ID`, `NAME`, `CREATED_AT`, `UPDATED_AT` are  all attributes that appear to relate directly to a Feature. The columns `ENV` and `ENABLED` relate to where and how that Feature is deployed. At first glance, that suggests storing this data in a completely separate table (possibly with `CREATED_AT` and `UPDATED_AT` to indicate when they were first deployed and last updated). I'd personally go with Feature, Environment and Feature_Environment as separate tables with Foreign Keys from Feature_Environment to the other two.

Comment: Thanks for your insight Paul. It's going to be a frequent query. E.g, if there is a feature to send notification on login then the query will run and a condition will check if the feature is enabled on every login of every user. This is just one use-case, there are many more. 'all' is there to keep the number of rows minimum, if feature is only disabled on say 'prod' then we need only two rows. The idea of having 3 tables is good from design point of view but that also means joining 3 tables in one the most executed query of the application. Tracking when feature was enabled is unimportant.

Comment: On thinking about the value `all` further after Rick Jame's answer. I think `all` is unnecessary and should be left aside. The advantage of faster query is greater than few records or convenience of insertion/updation

Comment: My issue with ALL was more to do with redundancy and ambiguity. With ALL you could end up with multiple records that record the same fact e.g. a record that indicated feature x is enabled in QA and another that feature x is enabled in ALL - these record the same fact. At the same time it also allowed for conflicting facts, e.g. feature x is disabled in ALL and feature x is enabled in QA.

Comment: Of course there is another way of looking at this. You don't build Features to then not deploy them or have them enabled. There will be instances where you won't want the feature enabled in a particular environment but that's normally the exception. You could assume a feature is enabled in an environment unless there is a record that records it as disabled. A disabled_features table doesn't even require a flag for enabled/disabled, the existence of the record tells you everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'religious' war waging between the pro-ENUM and anti-ENUM factions.  You have read one of the 'anti' articles.  But many of the "evils" in that article may not apply to your situation.

Your query can be sped up by getting rid if the current PK `id` and replacing it by

```
PRIMARY KEY(name, env)
```

After that, no secondary indexes are needed.

What you have requires a lookup in a secondary key, then reach into the PK to get the third column.  After that, sort and deliver one row.

Changing the PK avoids the extra lookup.  And there should be no "downside" to the change.

If you have millions of rows in the table, and you are likely to have thousands of candidates for each `env` value asked for, then this will be faster, because it does not gather "thousands" of rows, sort them, only to deliver one.  Instead it gets two rows and picks from them:

```
    (   SELECT  `enabled`
            FROM  `features`
            WHERE  `name` = 'some_featuere'
              AND  `env` = 'all'
            ORDER BY  `enabled` ASC
            limit  1
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    (  SELECT  `enabled`
            FROM  `features`
            WHERE  `name` = 'some_featuere'
              AND  `env` = 'qa'
            ORDER BY  `enabled` ASC
            limit  1 
    )
    ORDER BY  `enabled`
    LIMIT  1;
```

Yes, the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are repeated.  I do not recommend this `OR` --> `UNION` for small datasets because there are many steps, each with overhead.

My Answer applies whether you use ENUM or some other method.  It does assume InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different Answer -- using `SET` datatype.

Here are the table changes:

```
`env` SET('local', 'qa', 'staging', 'production') NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
```

No secondary keys, no `'all'`, only a single row per `name`.

However, the test becomes messier.  Or does it become simpler??  That is

```
AND `env` IN('all', 'qa')
```

-->

```
AND env = 'qa'
```

since a test is now for only one thing.  The messy `all` is gone.

If all that fits with the business logic, then the table and the query are simpler and faster.

If I am wrong on the business logic, please elaborate.  There may be a way to rescue this Answer (using `SET` and no `IN`).

Comment: I agree to leave `all` aside. The reason to bring `all` was to keep the number of rows minimum and making it convenient to insert/update records. But since we know that the insertion and updation on this table are rare and querying the table is very frequent, we should not worry about the number of rows or how convenient it is to insert new records.

Comment: @shehzadali - Doesn't the `SET` approach decrease the number of rows?  (One row per `name`.)